# node-red : lots of time to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a local instance of node-red with two nodes : http in and http out. But this simple node take 6 seconds to respon, and there are no process. It 's the same for mes others flows (5 / 6 others).

Someone has an idea ? Why it is really slow ?

EDIT : Response to coms :

It is not a code problem here. Below the flow :

[image: flow]

Network analysis (server in the cloud with a great download / upload speed): 
[image: network]

I have too 10 other flows on the node-red server, with mqtt nodes, http, udp etc... But all is slow. During execution, there are almost 5 sec when two flows communicate with HTTP.

The hardware part is ok : CPU i5, 8 Go RAM etc..

Comment: You have to show some code.

Comment: What hardware are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved ! It was due to a Arduino node.

There was a Arduino node on a flow but when I deleted it, the node configuration was always active, and looking for the arduino.. I delete the Arduino configuration in menu -> Nodes Configuration and all works fine !

Thanks.